# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'..why is this the case since i did not assign that statement to another variable

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, django-views, django-templates

```
AttributeError 
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

```
def func(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        html = request.POST.get('html')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        first_html = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')
        second_html = BeautifulSoup(''.join(open('file1.html')))
        for element in second_html:
            first_html.body.append(copy.copy(element))
```

I am trying to concatenate 2 html using Beautiful Soup, However i receive an error in the line: `first_html.body.append(copy.copy(element))` why is this the case since i did not assign that statement to another variable

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused because `first_html.body` is `None`, i.e. `BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')` returns `None` for the `body` attribute.

Comment: Why is this none? i did print(first_html) and I was able to print out all the codes in first_html @Michael Ruth

Comment: I can't answer this question without knowing the value of `html`

Comment: @longlong you printed `first_html` but you are appending on `first_html.body` which is `None`